# What does "the same" refer to when Lockhart says "In fact, I'm going to have to do the same to you."?

Tags: harry-potter

Lockhart says to Harry Potter and Ron:

> Lockhart: I'm rather gifted with Memory Charms. Otherwise, all those
> wizards would have gone blabbing. I'd never have sold another book. In
> fact, I'm going to have to do **the same** to you.

What does "the same" refer to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It refers to the Memory Charm. He is saying that just as he has performed Memory Charms on others so that they could not tell the truth about Lockhart's (lack of) accomplishments, he will now perform Memory Charms on Harry and Ron so that they too will be unable to reveal the truth.

The passage from the book has it as:

> "Awfully sorry boys, but I'll have to put a Memory Charm on you now. Can't have you blabbing my secrets all over the place. I'd never sell another book –"